# How to calculate year to date and 12 months variations in r

Tags: r

I have data of multiple years (in this example only 3). Need to calculate year to date and 12 months variations in r. Year-to-date variations are as follows:

1. Year to date variation January 2021= Value January 2021/ Value January 2020.
2. Year to date variation February 2021= Sum(Value January 2021: February 2021)/Sum(Value January 2020: February 2020)
3. Year to date variation March 2021= Sum(Value January 2021: March 2021)/Sum(Value January 2020: March 2020)

12 months variations are as follows:

1. 12 months variation January 2021= Sum (Value February 2020:Value January 2021)/ Sum(Value February 2019:Value January 2020).
2. 12 months variation February 2021= Sum (Value March 2020:Value February 2021)/ Sum(Value March 2019:Value February 2020).

   | Year | Month | Value | Year to date variations R | 12 mothns |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 2019 | 1 | 182 |  |  |
   | 2019 | 2 | 160 |  |  |
   | 2019 | 3 | 170 |  |  |
   | 2019 | 4 | 123 |  |  |
   | 2019 | 5 | 165 |  |  |
   | 2019 | 6 | 153 |  |  |
   | 2019 | 7 | 152 |  |  |
   | 2019 | 8 | 182 |  |  |
   | 2019 | 9 | 156 |  |  |
   | 2019 | 10 | 141 |  |  |
   | 2019 | 11 | 161 |  |  |
   | 2019 | 12 | 193 |  |  |
   | 2020 | 1 | 143 | 0,785714285714286 |  |
   | 2020 | 2 | 138 | 0,821637426900585 |  |
   | 2020 | 3 | 113 | 0,76953125 |  |
   | 2020 | 4 | 127 | 0,820472440944882 |  |
   | 2020 | 5 | 107 | 0,785 |  |
   | 2020 | 6 | 185 | 0,853095487932844 |  |
   | 2020 | 7 | 125 | 0,848868778280543 |  |
   | 2020 | 8 | 109 | 0,813519813519814 |  |
   | 2020 | 9 | 167 | 0,841302841302841 |  |
   | 2020 | 10 | 128 | 0,847222222222222 |  |
   | 2020 | 11 | 139 | 0,848710601719198 |  |
   | 2020 | 12 | 173 | 0,853457172342621 |  |
   | 2021 | 1 | 111 | 0,776223776223776 | 0,854133754607688 |
   | 2021 | 2 | 169 | 0,99644128113879 | 0,88066062866276 |
   | 2021 | 3 | 125 | 1,02791878172589 | 0,914835164835165 |
   | 2021 | 4 | 134 | 1,03454894433781 | 0,916666666666667 |
   | 2021 | 5 | 112 | 1,03662420382166 | 0,94960362400906 |
   | 2021 | 6 | 114 | 0,940959409594096 | 0,89321468298109 |
   | 2021 | 7 | 171 | 0,997867803837953 | 0,932806324110672 |
   | 2021 | 8 | 161 | 1,04775549188157 | 1,00353356890459 |
   | 2021 | 9 | 195 | 1,06425041186161 | 1,01345816266823 |
   | 2021 | 10 | 150 | 1,07451564828614 | 1,03419811320755 |
   | 2021 | 11 | 181 | 1,09588116137745 | 1,07287933094385 |
   | 2021 | 12 | 163 | 1,07980652962515 | 1,07980652962515 |

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by leveraging the power of `data.table::shift()`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df <- df[order(Month,Year),p:=shift(Value),Month] %>% 
  .[,ytd_var:=cumsum(Value)/cumsum(p),Year] %>% 
  .[,`:=`(mon_var=Reduce(`+`, shift(Value,0:11))/Reduce(`+`, shift(Value,12:23)), p=NULL)]
```

Explanation:

1. First, get the 12-month prior value (`p`) for each month, by ordering by Month and  Year, and using `shift(Value)`, by Month.
2. Then, create the year-to-date value (`ytd_var`) by dividing the cumulative sum of `Value` by the cumulative sum of `p`, by Year.
3. Finally, create the 12-month variation value (`mon_var`) by dividing the sum of `Value` in the current and prior 11 months by the sum of `Value` in months 12 thru 23 prior to the current month. Notice that I use `Reduce()` to sum over all these prior values.

Output:

```
    Year Month Value   ytd_var   mon_var
 1: 2019     1   182        NA        NA
 2: 2019     2   160        NA        NA
 3: 2019     3   170        NA        NA
 4: 2019     4   123        NA        NA
 5: 2019     5   165        NA        NA
 6: 2019     6   153        NA        NA
 7: 2019     7   152        NA        NA
 8: 2019     8   182        NA        NA
 9: 2019     9   156        NA        NA
10: 2019    10   141        NA        NA
11: 2019    11   161        NA        NA
12: 2019    12   193        NA        NA
13: 2020     1   143 0.7857143        NA
14: 2020     2   138 0.8216374        NA
15: 2020     3   113 0.7695312        NA
16: 2020     4   127 0.8204724        NA
17: 2020     5   107 0.7850000        NA
18: 2020     6   185 0.8530955        NA
19: 2020     7   125 0.8488688        NA
20: 2020     8   109 0.8135198        NA
21: 2020     9   167 0.8413028        NA
22: 2020    10   128 0.8472222        NA
23: 2020    11   139 0.8487106        NA
24: 2020    12   173 0.8534572 0.8534572
25: 2021     1   111 0.7762238 0.8541338
26: 2021     2   169 0.9964413 0.8806606
27: 2021     3   125 1.0279188 0.9148352
28: 2021     4   134 1.0345489 0.9166667
29: 2021     5   112 1.0366242 0.9496036
30: 2021     6   114 0.9409594 0.8932147
31: 2021     7   171 0.9978678 0.9328063
32: 2021     8   161 1.0477555 1.0035336
33: 2021     9   195 1.0642504 1.0134582
34: 2021    10   150 1.0745156 1.0341981
35: 2021    11   181 1.0958812 1.0728793
36: 2021    12   163 1.0798065 1.0798065
```

Input:

```
df = structure(list(Year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L), Month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), Value = c(182L, 
160L, 170L, 123L, 165L, 153L, 152L, 182L, 156L, 141L, 161L, 193L, 
143L, 138L, 113L, 127L, 107L, 185L, 125L, 109L, 167L, 128L, 139L, 
173L, 111L, 169L, 125L, 134L, 112L, 114L, 171L, 161L, 195L, 150L, 
181L, 163L)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```